# How to trigger anchor link after waiting for separate ajaxcomplete event

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, onblur

Here's my scenario to help you people understand my problem.

1. on my page i have onblur event attached to many input fields.
2. onblur event calls server side method, Method1, to set a flag and return true/false

   function compute() {

   $('#processing').attr("value", true);

   ```
   $.ajax({
       url: '/Method1',
       type: 'POST',
       contentType: 'application/json;',
       data: JSON.stringify({ quantiter: 10}),
       success: function (data) {
           if (data == "true") {
              //set icon
               $('#processing').attr("value", false);
           }
       },
       error: function () {

       }
   });
   ```

   }
3. on true, i update my UI, i insert a small icon to indicate the field has changed

The problem i am facing is that:
after modifying an input, the user can click on save button which triggers a different server side method, Method2.

```
<a onclick="Sauvegarder()">Save</a>


function Sauvegarder() {        
    var newProcessor =  $('#processing').attr("value");
    ...cal Method 2
}
```

So, the onblur event calls the Method1 but it does not complete, and Method2 gets called before Method1 completes.

With this, the small icon is not set.

Aim: my aim is to get the result from the onblur event, set my icon then call Method2 when save button is clicked.

So far i have tried to declare a global js variable: processing.
I set this var to true, when i call Method1, and on success, i set it to false.

When Save is clicked, i check the value of processing. 
If it is false, meaning Method 1 has completed, I call Method2. 
The problem with this solution is that, the value of js variable processing is checked only once and it may/may not be set yet.

What can be the other ways of doing this?

Comment: You can bind the onclick event for the anchor tag in the success function

Comment: Which will mean that the user will have to click twice on the Save button. Isn't it?

Comment: Your first method is called from the blur event as you said, which means for calling method 2 you just have to click once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Method1',
    type: 'POST',
    async: false
    contentType: 'application/json;',
    data: JSON.stringify({ quantiter: 10}),
    success: function (data) {
        if (data == "true") {
           //set icon
            $('#processing').attr("value", false);
        }
    },
    error: function () {

    }
});
```

Set `async : false` for the AJAX call.

Comment: It works on Chrome but not in Firefox. When I click the Save button in Firefox, I check the request being submitted. I saw the onblur event being triggered, but not the Save event (call Method2 not being done). I need to click again to trigger it. Any idea what's the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the jquery method `.ajaxComplete()`. Here is the link [ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/)

If you add async:false , then it will not become ajax call , it becomes synchronous call. But I must admit that that's an option too..